# Unable to serialize object having Hashtable as a property in Jersy restful service

Tags: java, rest, jersey, hashtable

I am using sun jersey to implement restful services using java. But it seems jersey framework is unable to serialize an object having **Hashtable** as its property.Below is code snippet.

Rest service code:

```
@Path("/get-test-infos")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getTests(Test test) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    ResponseBuilder builder = new ResponseBuilderImpl();
    MyTest mtest=new MyTest();
    Dictionary<Integer,String> intString=new Hashtable<Integer,String>();
    List<Integer> intList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    intList.add(1);
    intList.add(2);
    intString.put(1, "one");
    intString.put(2, "two");
    mtest.setIntString(intString);
    mtest.setIntList(intList);
    builder.entity(mtest);
    builder.status(Status.OK);
    return builder.build();
}
```

MyTest class definition:

```
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.List;

public class MyTest {
    private int testId;
    private Dictionary<Integer,String> intString;
    private List<Integer>intList;
    public int getTestId() {
        return testId;
    }
    public void setTestId(int testId) {
        this.testId = testId;
    }
    public Dictionary<Integer,String> getIntString() {
        return intString;
    }
    public void setIntString(Dictionary<Integer,String> intString) {
        this.intString = intString;
    }
    public List<Integer> getIntList() {
        return intList;
    }
    public void setIntList(List<Integer> intList) {
        this.intList = intList;
    }
}
```

Below is pom.xml content:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>OnePlatformEduService_v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>OnePlatformEduService_v3</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>DatabaseModule</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

<!-- jdbc driver for Postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.14.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.14.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

While trying to fetch the json response, getting following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] in context with path [/OnePlatformEduService_v3] threw exception
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: practise.MyTest["intString"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:180)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.SerializerBase.wrapAndThrow(SerializerBase.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:253)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:587)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:245)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1145)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:520)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.writeTo(JacksonProviderProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.createTypeSerializer(BasicSerializerFactory.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.buildMapSerializer(BasicSerializerFactory.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerByLookup(BasicSerializerFactory.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:734)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:404)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.PropertySerializerMap.findAndAddSerializer(PropertySerializerMap.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._findAndAddDynamic(BeanPropertyWriter.java:443)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:245)
    ... 36 more
```

I am getting following exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: practise.MyTest["intString"])
```

Please help me to resolve above issue.

Comment: please try adding jackson dependency

Comment: I added but no benefit.